# q - string representation of list

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a list

```
filter:((in;`name;`betsy`robert`tom);(>;`age;43));
```

and I would like to get the following list representation out of it

```
"((in;`name;`betsy`robert`tom);(>;`age;43))"
```

What I found so far is this:

```
flatten:{[alist]
    $[(count alist)~count raze alist;:alist;:flatten raze alist];
    };
";" sv string raze flatten[filter]
/ gives: "in;name;betsy;robert;tom;>;age;43"
```

which loses the nested lists in the `filter` list.

credits to: https://lifeisalist.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/p07-flatten-a-nested-list-structure/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the command you are looking for is [`.Q.s`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qs-plain-text) or `.Q.s1` which return kdb code in plain text:

```
q).Q.s1 filter
"((in;`name;`betsy`robert`tom);(>;`age;43))"
```

It should be noted that the output of these functions is limited by [`\c`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/syscmds/#c-console-size).